# InnerHtml & textarea simply ignores newline

Tags: javascript, textarea, newline

I got a `document.getElementById("myTextArea").innerHTML = 'Hi \n There'` I execute into an editable textarea,
and for some reasons the moment I add \n to it, it doesn't display the text at all, if I keep the "Hi" it outputs it just fine, no problems with space either, it just ignores newline, or any other things like /r.

My  `<textarea id="myTextArea" contenteditable="true" placeholder="empty"></textarea>`

I tried also `.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />')` but it outputs the `<br />` as text instead.

Comment: have you tried putting your content(new line included) between starting and ending textarea tag?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Hi Emilien and welcome to Stack Overflow. My congratulations, by trying something nobody ever thought anyone would try, you've found a quirk in browser behavior. While textarea elements only take text content, FireFox renders the content of an `innerHTML` property set on a `<textarea>` if and only if you haven't set its `value` property first. Using `contenteditable` in a `<texatarea>` tag makes no logical sense - text areas are editable by nature. Solution: don't set innerHTML on a text area or add a contenteditable  attribute. Text area elements are **not** intended to work this way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the textarea element's value instead of innerHTML.

`const string = "Test\nTest"; document.getElementById("text").value =string;`

```js
const string = "Test\nTest";
document.getElementById("text").value =string;
```

```html
<textarea id=text></textarea>
```

Comment: doesn't work either for some reasons.

Comment: did you put anything in css?

Comment: I tried adding white-spaces into the textarea{} but same results

Comment: ok then I'm sorry then unfortunately I have no more ideas.  I would recommend you to recreate the jsfiddle and add your code step by step.  you will probably find the one point where the textarea is acting weird.

Comment: Made you a snippet.